# Problems with understanding code in C(STDIN_FILENO)

Tags: c, unix, stdin, system-calls

me and my friend have problems understanding code. We don't understand why at the end it is checked if the nread is != 1. Can someone help us we would be very glad.

```
while ((nread = read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1)) != 1) {
        if (nread == -1 && errno != EAGAIN) quit("read");
    }
```

Comment: Please note that [a certain amount of research is expected before asking a question on Stack Overflow](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/). This includes reading the [documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) of the function `read`. According to the linked documentation, the function `read` will, if it is successful, return the number of bytes read, which should be `1` in this case (because that is the amount of data that was requested). That is why the return value is compared with the value `1`, and if it is not equal, then the program quits with an error message.

Comment: My previous comment was not quite accurate. The program does not always quit with an error message when `nread != 1`. It only does this if also the conditions on line 2 are fulfilled.

Answer (score 1):

It causes the loop to be exited only once the read is successful.

That said, the code is buggy.

---

A call to `read` returns one of the following:

- -1, on error.
- 0, on EOF.
- [1,`count`], the number of bytes read.

Since this particular call to `read` only attempts to read one byte, the following are the possible values returned:

- -1, on error.
- 0, on EOF.
- 1, on a successful read.

So, let's look at the snippet as a whole.

- On error other than EAGAIN, it quits.
- On error EAGAIN, it tries again.
- On eof, it tries again.
- On a successful read, it continues beyond the loop.

This is problematic for two reasons.

- Its handling of EAGAIN is incorrect

  EAGAIN is returned for non-blocking handles when no data is available. As such, this is a busy-wait loop (one that hogs that CPU). That's not acceptable.

  Also, if the handle can be a socket, EWOULDBLOCK can be returned instead of EAGAIN. That's not handled at all.
- Its handling of EOF is incorrect

  On EOF, it attempts to read again. That's bad.

  Now, it's possible to read from certain handles after they've returned EOF. Specifically, terminals can reset their EOF status after returning EOF. But there's no guarantee that STDIN is a terminal. And even it was known that STDIN is a terminal, it could still return an endless stream of EOF just like any other handle.